# Show NSString array as circle with CGContext (works), but without angle?

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation, nsstring

I have a function that draws an NSArray with NSStrings as a circle. It works fine so far. The array tokens are displayed from the given start angle to the given end angle.
As I understand the way this code works, it first places the string at a normal angle. After this, the string gets rotated the wished angle with the given radius around the center. The result is, that the string is at the right place around the circle with a certain angle that came with the rotation.

It looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, it's getting hard to read the numbers which are upside down.So it would be better if the strings would have a 0° rotation angle. Is there a way to prevent the resulting angle of the string or rotate them back, after they're put on place?
Thanks for any tipps.

This is the function which actually draws the strings around the circle in the middle:

```
-(void)createScale{

scaleText =@[@"-5",@"-4",@"-3",@"-2",@"-1",@"0",@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5"];
// Start drawing

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// Retrieve the center and set a radius

CGFloat r = _center.x;

// Start by adjusting the context origin
// This affects all subsequent operations
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, _center.x, _center.y);

// Iterate through the alphabet
for (int i = 0; i < self.scaleText.count; i++)
{
    UIFont* font =[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20.0];
    // Retrieve the letter and measure its display size
    NSString *letter =
    [self.scaleText objectAtIndex:i];
    //CGSize letterSize =[letter sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:@"Helvetica"}];
    CGSize size = [letter sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font}];
    CGFloat theta;
    // Calculate the current angular offset
    if(_endAngle-_startAngle<0){
        theta = i * (DEG2RAD(_startAngle-_endAngle)/ (float) (self.scaleText.count+1))-DEG2RAD(360-_startAngle);
    }else{
        theta = i * (DEG2RAD(_endAngle-_startAngle)/ (float) (self.scaleText.count-1))-DEG2RAD(360-_startAngle);}

    // Encapsulate each stage of the drawing
    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    // Rotate the context

    CGContextRotateCTM(context, theta);

    // Translate up to the edge of the radius and move left by
    // half the letter width. The height translation is negative
    // as this drawing sequence uses the UIKit coordinate system.
    // Transformations that move up go to lower y values.

    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -size.width / 2, -r);
    UIColor* fontColor=[UIColor blackColor];

    //colors lowest, or highest number in string
    if(i==0 && ((NSString*)[self.scaleText objectAtIndex:i]).intValue<0){
        fontColor=[UIColor redColor];
    }
    if(i==self.scaleText.count-1&& ((NSString*)[self.scaleText objectAtIndex:self.scaleText.count-1]).intValue>0){
        fontColor=[UIColor greenColor];
    }

    // Draw the letter and pop the transform state

    [letter drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)
         withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font,NSForegroundColorAttributeName : fontColor }];
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

}

**###ADDED###**

As Duncan C suggested, I dropped the CGContext stuff and did the placement of the text with Trig.

```
-(void)createScale{

// Start drawing

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
// Retrieve the center
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, _center.x, _center.y);

// Iterate through the array
for (int i = 0; i < self.scaleText.count; i++)
{
    UIFont* font =[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20.0];
    // Retrieve the letter and measure its display size
    NSString *letter =[self.scaleText objectAtIndex:i];

    UIColor* fontColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    //colors lowest, or highest number in string
    if(i==0 && ((NSString*)[self.scaleText objectAtIndex:self.scaleText.count-1]).intValue<=0){
        fontColor=[UIColor redColor];
    }
    if(i==self.scaleText.count-1&& ((NSString*)[self.scaleText objectAtIndex:self.scaleText.count-1]).intValue>0){
        fontColor=[UIColor greenColor];
    }

    CGFloat theta;
    // Calculate the current angular offset

    //when overturn
    if(_endAngle-_startAngle<0){
        theta = i * (DEG2RAD(_startAngle-_endAngle)/ (float) (self.scaleText.count+1))+DEG2RAD(_startAngle);
        //normal case
    }else{
        theta = i * (DEG2RAD(_endAngle-_startAngle)/ (float) (self.scaleText.count-1))+DEG2RAD(_startAngle);}

    CGFloat y = round(cosf(theta) * _radiusScale) ;
    CGFloat x = round(sinf(theta) * _radiusScale) ;
    // Draw the letter and pop the transform state
    [letter drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(x, -y) withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font,NSForegroundColorAttributeName : fontColor }];
}

}
```

Now the strings do find somehow their place in a zero 0° angle, but I do get a weird offset, which from I have no idea where it could come from. I've fighting around with this the last couple hours and still have no solution for this.

[image]

Comment: I'd get rid of the CGContextTranslateCTM call and simply use the center of your circle as the base for your calculation (add the calculated circle point coordinates to the center point). Then you can log your numbers and figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't rotate the strings at all then. Instead, use trig (sine and cosine) to calculate the center position for each string.

Here's how you figure out how to use trig to find the center points for the numbers you want to draw:

Remember the mnemonic for the trig functions: SOA CAH TOA

```
sine = opposite over adjacent
cosine= adjacent over hypotenuse
tangent = opposite over adjacent
```

Draw out a  circle centered on the origin of a graph. Put a right triangle in the first quadrant, with one corner at the center of the circle, another corner somewhere along the circle between 0 and 45 degrees. Drop a vertical line from that point down to the x axis. The angle we're using in our functions is the angle at the center of the circle. The hypotenuse is the line from the center of the circle to the edge. The adjacent side is the horizontal leg of the triangle (x). The side opposite the angle is the vertical leg of the triangle (y).

```
sine(angle) = x/radius
x = radius * sine(angle)

cos(angle) = y/radius
y = radius * cos(angle)
```

Now you have a formula for calculating the center point of a number based on the angle and the desired circle radius. Use that formula to place your numbers around the circle.

I have a [**project on github**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/ClockAnimation) (link) that draws a clock face using exactly this approach.

Comment: I think that is exactly what I've been searching for.My mind is always trying to dodge trigonometry ;) Thanks a lot. I'll try to work it out like this and will post a response.

Comment: Trig is probably the single most important bit of high school math for computer graphics. Go back and study it until you're comfortable with it, or you'll struggle with this every time you need to do calculations with angles and distances. Native American chief SOH CAH TOA is your friend.

Comment: The german equivalent to the chief is GAGA/HHAG :)
I did it like this, but this brought me to another problem.

Comment: Can you accept this answer if it answered your question? It helps people know that the question is resolved.

Comment: Sorry about assuming US English. What does GAGA/HHAG stand for in German? And how does it help you remember sine, cosine, and tangent? The US English mnemonic SOH CAH TOA lets you remember all 3 "base" trig functions.

Comment: GAGA/HHAG even lets you remind cotangent.
G stands for opposite
A stands for adjacent
H stands for hypothenuse
and you write GAGA above HHAG looking like this
http://www.cheesebuerger.de/smiliegenerator/ablage/187/217.png